# Peoplesoft rowset

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I'm new to peoplesoft. I need a help in understanding the rowset and I have a requirement where i have 3 levels.

On level 1 i have a checkbox and when I open a component the value of the checkbox on level 1 should be passed and display to the level 2 grid for all rows.

### For example

level0 - record1
level1 - record2 (Scroll Area)

level2 - record3 (grid)

When i access the page it should have values like this

Record2.field1 = Y => Row1 Record3.field1 = Y
                      Row2 Record3.field1 = Y

---

Record2.field1 = N => Row1 Record3.field1 = N

---

I have written the code at level2 record.field rowinit peoplecode event. but the problem is the same record field is used in level 0 as well. Is there a way where I can avoid using for loop as there could be n number of rows in the grid which might create a performance issue during page opening.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Rowinit will fire for each rows in the scroll. So if you have a loop in the rowinit, loop will execute for each row.

If you want the check box to be set only during the component load, you can add the peoplecode in Component PostBuild.

```
&rsLevel1 = GetLevel0()(1).GetRowSet(Scroll.Level1);
for &nCnt1 = 1 to &rsLevel1.activerowcount
   &rsLevel2 = &rsLevel1(&nCnt1).GetRowset(Scroll.Level2);
   for &nCnt2 = 1 to &rsLevel2.activerowcount
      &rsLevel2(&nCnt2).Level2.Check_box.value = &rsLevel1(&nCnt1).Level1.Check_box.value
   end-for;
end-for;
```